# Newbie Android 4.4 Hello Word App Crash Issue - Button click changes/updates TextView

Tags: android, pointers, exception, null, android-4.4-kitkat

Android newb here.  Writing my first hello world app and can't get past two "Unfortunately" errors and a crash.  I am going to guess it's a null pointer exception, but no amount of Googling makes me understand it any better.  Thank you so much in advance.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.eventexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.eventexample.EventExampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>        
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

EventExampleActivity.java

```
package com.example.eventexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EventExampleActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        Button button = 
                (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);

            button.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
                        myTextView.setText("Button clicked");
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

activity_event_example.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".EventExampleActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/mybutton_string" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:text="@string/mytextview_string"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Console Dump

```
[2014-07-06 21:35:36 - EventExample] ------------------------------
[2014-07-06 21:35:36 - EventExample] Android Launch!
[2014-07-06 21:35:36 - EventExample] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-06 21:35:36 - EventExample] Performing com.example.eventexample.EventExampleActivity activity launch
[2014-07-06 21:35:38 - EventExample] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-07-06 21:35:38 - EventExample] Starting activity com.example.eventexample.EventExampleActivity on device 192.168.56.101:5555
[2014-07-06 21:35:38 - EventExample] ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
[2014-07-06 21:35:39 - EventExample] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.eventexample/.EventExampleActivity }
```

LogCat dump

```
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681): Process: com.example.eventexample, PID: 1681
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eventexample/com.example.eventexample.EventExampleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at com.example.eventexample.EventExampleActivity.onStart(EventExampleActivity.java:25)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
07-07 02:35:38.276: E/AndroidRuntime(1681):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: If you have created an activity from the new activity wizard,you would have had setContentView() in onCreate() and not onStart().

setContentView() is always set in onCreate() ,not onStart()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
public class EventExampleActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_example);
    Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
                    myTextView.setText("Button clicked");
                }
            }
    );
}

}
```

In your activity you have to override the onCreate method and call: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_example)`. The other answers are partially correct, both of them told you to write **setContentView(R.id.activity_event_example);**, instead you should write **setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_example);**. It should be **R.layout.your_xml**, because xmls are defined inside layout class, not inside id class.

If you look up inside R.java file then you will find something like

```
public static final class layout {
    public static final int your_xml_name=0x7f030000;
   }
```

So change `id` to `layout`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to let the activity know which xml is to render for UI. So, in your activity override the onCreate method and add this call: setContentView(R.id.activity_event_example)

Also move the code you have right now in the onStart method into onCreate (it's called once, while onStart is called every time your screen is brought to the foreground), but **after** the call to setContentView

Comment: setContentView(R.id.activity_event_example); line errors out with "cannot be resolved or is not a field".  Thanks.

Comment: @ArtemCherkes It should be `setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_example);`

Answer (score 0):

Generally code that creates GUI stuff should go into `onCreate()` and you need to call `setContentView()` before `findViewById()`

Your class should look like this:

```
public class EventExampleActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_example);
    Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
                    myTextView.setText("Button clicked");
                }
            }
    );
}

}
```

UPDATE:
Indeed it should not read R.id. but R.layout.
I edited the code so that it should now be correct.

Comment: Thanks, it's complaining that activity_event_example cannot be resolved or is not a field.  Assuming this is the reference to the layout file?

Comment: Yes @ArtemCherkes, you must call a reference to your layout file, example: R.layout.file_name

Comment: Hmm ... look at the error it's throwing.  Is there another place in the project I have to reference it?  http://i.imgur.com/buFUfXp.png

Comment: @ArtemCherkes please check my answer. It should be `R.layout.your_xml` not `R.id.your_xml`.